# jquery nth-child issue

Tags: jquery

My code is like this:

```
var childNo = 2;
$('#someSelector tr:nth-child(childNo) td:first span').addClass('font-strike');
```

but it doesn't add the class. If i replace childNo with 2 it works fine. any idea how i can get it to work?

Comment: `var childNo = parseInt(2);` try this

Comment: no need of parsing.. its solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're putting the string literal 'childNo' into your selector.  replace it with:

```
$('#someSelector tr:nth-child('+childNo+') td:first span').addClass('font-strike');
```

and it should work

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your variable like :

> $('#someSelector
>   tr:nth-child('+childNo'+) td:first
>   span').addClass('font-strike');

Answer (score 0):

$('#someSelector tr:nth-child(' + childNo + ' ) td:first span').addClass('font-strike');